How to get insight in the relations between tracebacks of exceptions in an exception-chain
This question is best introduced example-first:
Consider the following trivial program:
class OriginalException(Exception):
    pass


class AnotherException(Exception):
    pass


def raise_another_exception():
    raise AnotherException()


def show_something():
    try:
        raise OriginalException()
    except OriginalException:
        raise_another_exception()


show_something()

running this will dump the following on screen (minus annotations on the Right-Hand-Side):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...../stackoverflow_single_complication.py", line 15, in show_something                 t1
    raise OriginalException()
__main__.OriginalException

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...../stackoverflow_single_complication.py", line 20, in <module>                       t0
    show_something()
  File "...../stackoverflow_single_complication.py", line 17, in show_something                 t2
    raise_another_exception()
  File "...../stackoverflow_single_complication.py", line 10, in raise_another_exception        t3
    raise AnotherException()
__main__.AnotherException

What we see here is first the OriginalException with the stackframes between the moment that it was raised and the moment it was handled.
Then we see AnotherException, with a complete traceback from its point-of-raising to the start of the program (all frames)
In itself this is perfectly fine, but a consequence of this way of presenting the information is that the stackframes are not laid out on the screen in the order in which they were called (and not in the reverse order either), as per the annotations t1, t0, t2, t3. The path leading up to t1 is of course the same as the path leading up to t2, and the creators of Python have chosen to present it only once, in the latter case, presumably because that Exception is usually the most interesting one, and because it allows one to read the bottom exception bottom-up without loss of information. However, it does leave people that want to analyze the OriginalException somewhat mystified: what led up to it?
A programmer that wants to understand what led up to t1 would need to [mentally] copy all the frames above the point t2 to the first stacktrace to get a complete view. However, in reality the point t2 is, AFAIK, not automatically annotated for you as a special frame, which makes the task of mentally copying the stacktrace much harder.
Since the point t2 is in general "the failing line in the except block", by cross-referencing the source-code this excercise can usually be completed, but this seems unnecessarily hard.
Is it possible to automatically pinpoint t2 as the "handling frame"?
(The example above is given without some outer exception-handling context; I'm perfectly fine with answers that introduce it and then use traceback or other tools to arrive at the correct answer).
This is the most trivial case that illustrates the problem; real cases have many more stack frames and thus less clearly illustrate the problem but more clearly illustrate the need for (potentially automated) clarification of what's happening that this SO question is about.
Edit to add:
I wrote a full blog post on  Chained Exceptions in Python
